# Has anybody had any luck using google's 3d model viewer or alternatives in rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 3d

I am trying to render some 3d models on a small project, but my level is not advanced enough to use something like Three.js.

When looking for options, i came across google's  [alternative](https://modelviewer.dev/) and gave it a try, but I can't seem to find a way to import a static file to the asset pipeline. When inputing only the resource location into src, also nothing.
Environment is set to dev, and the folder has been added to assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.enabled = true
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', '3d')
```

```
<% provide(:title, "3d View") %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="module" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/model-viewer/3.1.1/model-viewer.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <model-viewer
        alt="3D Car Model"
        src=<%=asset_path('3d/300selBlender.glb')%>
        ar
        shadow-intensity="1"
        camera-controls
        touch-action="pan-y"
    ></model-viewer>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sorry if this seems too basic, but any kind of help would be very welcome.